# Kafka RoundRobin partitioner not distributing messages to 4 partitions

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have 4 brokers and 4 partitions but when I try to push 4 messages with null key it’s not saving as round robin.I was expecting message will save it in each partition once.

Using kafka-clients 5.5* for getting KafkaProducer and it looks like version after 5.4* ,

If a key is not provided, behavior is Confluent Platform version-dependent:

In Confluent Platform versions 5.4.x and later, the partition is assigned with awareness to batching. If a batch of records is not full and has not yet been sent to the broker, it will select the same partition as a prior record. Partitions for newly created batches are assigned randomly. For more information, see KIP-480: Sticky Partitioner and the related Confluent blog post.
In Confluent Platform versions prior to 5.4.x, the partition is assigned in a round robin method, starting at a random partition.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/producer.html

Is my understanding correct or not ?

Comment: could you add your producer code and config?

Comment: Please add some details ( code, logcat messages )  so to understand what is

Comment: Updated with details.

Answer (score 1):

A new partitioner (StickyPartitioner) was introduced in Kafka version 2.4 for improving the way in which data is sent to the partitions by the producer.

Basically, now it batches the data first and then does a round robin instead of doing round robin for each and every record.

For more details, you cam refer to the below link. It explains everything is detail.

https://www.confluent.io/blog/5-things-every-kafka-developer-should-know/#tip-2-new-sticky-partitioner